# Best wording for "edit X" button?

Tags: dashboard, admin, wording, content-management

What is the best wording for an "edit section" button and why? The pages I am linking to will be for adding and editing existing items. For example it could contain one of:

- Manage Pages
- Add/Edit Pages
- Pages (Leading to section with separate add and edit links)

Or maybe just 2 separate menu entries:

- Add Page
- Edit Page

These are all clear to me but my target users will be about 40+ and unfortunately very un-savvy when it comes to tech. They will be included in a dashboard like so:
[image]

Comment: I cannot say that I am tech-savvy, but I consider myself not very un-savvy.  However, it would baffle me if a menu consists of items called “Manage Pages,” “Add/Edit Pages,” and “Pages,” because they all sound the same to me.  Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Those were choices, not going to use them all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for a 40+ user group, avoid 'manage' itself. Make the links even more self-explanatory.

'Create New Page'
'Edit a Page'
'Add/Edit Categories'
'Approve/Remove Comments'

non-tech savvy ppl have a tendency to get lost in the page structure, so a link called 'Pages' which has links to 'add page' and 'edit page' will add to confusion. Ofc if you have 20+ links in your homepage rather than the 4 shown here, I would use a slider to show 'Add page' and 'edit page' once the user clicks on 'Pages', mimicking a down-down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Both, *1.Add Page 2.Edit Page* is as clear as *Add/Edit Pages* and *Manage Pages*. My opinion is to avoid Pages because of your users.

However, what to choose between your 3 options it depends on the structure of your application. What I mean is that if your pages.php allow a user to add and edit a post at once, then you should go for the *Add/Edit Pages* or *Manage Pages*. Prefer to use the first one.

On the other hand if you have an addpage.php and editpage.php it is logical that you will go with the *1.Add Page 2.Edit Page* option.

I was building a blogging system with two choices.

1. Write a post
2. Share a post from an external link

I was surprised on how many people used option 1 to paste a link to an external blog.

Concluding, avoid Pages, choose between *1.Add Page 2.Edit Page* or *Add/Edit Pages*.